# How do you evaluate and compare the value of item.istaxable in Netsuite?

Tags: freemarker, netsuite

I'm using the Advanced PDF/HTML Templates in Netsuite to create a custom output template. In this Template I want to evaluate an item to see if it is taxable.

NetSuite's Schema Defines a `Sales Order` with a Sub List `Item` that has a field `.istaxable` [(source)](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_2/script/record/salesorder.html)

- Field: istaxable
- Type: checkbox
- Label: Tax
- Required: false

When I try to evaluate an expression such as:

`<#if item.istaxable == true>`

By printing the template I get the following error.

> Left hand operand is a com.netledger.templates.model.StringModel
>
> Right hand operand is a freemarker.template.TemplateBooleanModel$2

When I try to evaluate .istaxable as a String:

```
<#if item.istaxable == "true">
```

or

```
<#if item.istaxable == 'T'>
```

*EDIT: Updated in response to suggested answer

I am unable to save the template in the editor as it throws an error:

> The only legal comparisons are between two numbers, two strings, or
>   two dates. Left hand operand is a
>   com.netledger.templates.model.BooleanModel Right hand operand is a
>   freemarker.template.SimpleScalar

So is `item.istaxable` a StringModel or a BooleanModel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netsuite is notoriously inconsistent with how it treats boolean values, and in fact I have come across cases where the *same* field is treated differently depending on the transaction (in my case it was the `isclosed` field). I ended up using the syntax below:

```
<#if (item.isclosed?is_boolean && item.isclosed) || (item.isclosed?is_string && item.isclosed == 'T')
```

Comment: Nice coverage of the cases.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried item.istaxable = 'T'?  That is what I use in SuiteScript 1.0

Comment: Did you mean '==' or just the single '='?

Comment: Its '==', sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

<#if item.istaxable>.....

Should function as a true/false evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

If Netsuite has set the `boolean_format` setting correctly, then the following should work:

```
<#if "${item.istaxable}" == "T">
```

If istaxable is a string, then its evaluation produces the Netsuite 'T'.  If istaxable is a boolean, then the `boolean_format` setting is used to convert it to a string; if true maps to 'T' and false maps to 'F', then it produces the same result as the string version.

YMMV - If I remember, I'll try to update this answer.